# Extracted the certificate chain from the BinarySecurityToken having format x509'. Hash values do not match from client'

Tags: wcf

How do I debug this error;' Hash values do not match from client'

My outgoing matches the vendor sample

Vendor sample

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mhs="http://org/emedny/mhs/" xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v3">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d">MIICeDCC....(eMedNY signed user MLS cert).......</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685">MIIDFj.....( eMedNY MLS web-service end-point public cert)........</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-970e9a80-00cc-4c86-8ec4-3ba16e029a5b">
<wsse:Username>....your_username.....</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">.....your_plaintext_password....</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce>KNyu6MsXCkTg4DDyvwvEiw==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2010-09-15T18:00:30Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
<xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
<wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>gpBAWt91pdwhKva............</xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:ReferenceList>
<xenc:DataReference URI="#Enc-0641b860-b16d-4941-91c0-d60bece67794"/>
</xenc:ReferenceList>
</xenc:EncryptedKey>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#Id-f10674fd-b999-47c9-9568-c11fa5e5405b">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>wRUq.........</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>tBSsaZi........</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
<wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="Id-f10674fd-b999-47c9-9568-c11fa5e5405b" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<xenc:EncryptedData Id="Enc-0641b860-b16d-4941-91c0-d60bece67794" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>SQsTCAK6ZaVhojB8+Y.........</xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedData>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

THis is my Outgoing Soap generated using CustomBinding

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Header>
        <ActivityId CorrelationId="06691695-887b-4f3e-a2c2-619ec48c82bb" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-4000-0080010000fa</ActivityId>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
          <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-4c068bc9-bfff-4601-ad57-351c23524c38-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Removed=</o:BinarySecurityToken>
          <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-4c068bc9-bfff-4601-ad57-351c23524c38-1" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Removed</o:BinarySecurityToken>
          <o:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <o:Username>LMWARD</o:Username>
            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Cardon0319</o:Password>
            <o:Nonce>wz6wpiWcKvX7bMj+LWlMaI7GmLg=</o:Nonce>
            <o:Created>2013-06-28T12:22:42.768Z</o:Created>
          </o:UsernameToken>
          <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
              <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-4c068bc9-bfff-4601-ad57-351c23524c38-1" />
              </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
            <e:CipherData>
              <e:CipherValue>kCO2Mf7mGCyLkpnHNADnid9eby850qjLkaKGMdXljSiXoFYW8ndppyF+1FSP9/zFqx2nPprtFo8y+G9iV7ahqfokAzlnX6KoTNExiZ/bqtzlJL9INF5PXrK8XQl3MCPHUUkhRtT3OhvgB/5+ubzEafR4Ays7ezspMAWu/UJnCMY=</e:CipherValue>
            </e:CipherData>
            <e:ReferenceList>
              <e:DataReference URI="#_2" />
            </e:ReferenceList>
          </e:EncryptedKey>
          <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
              <Reference URI="#_1">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>'l6kqP048t5INzJT3W8gxVSXplaE=</DigestValue>
              </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>gCwFapZ3D/vUXsvAShTQwNWJoA23ad54NRmUWXR7IBFbsr75HBdZUG5lO1Af+ncShzwJA2a6jJXJmw/1gKswyAP9QuZsa9D+6fGh8jwcVqjm5v/Sh9rgQxWjL6U1kkovP0IAqEjafRu6YgmauFVCHUrJ2QfIN96WYTPnYm9Puvs=</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
              <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-4c068bc9-bfff-4601-ad57-351c23524c38-2" />
              </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
          </Signature>
        </o:Security>
      </s:Header>
      <s:Body u:Id="_1" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
          <e:CipherData>
            <e:CipherValue>Removed</e:CipherValue>
          </e:CipherData>
        </e:EncryptedData>
      </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

This is additional content from vendor log

```
  Evaluating signature reference '_1'
trans(157350727)[request][12.23.28.110]: Current XPath expression '/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']' covered by signature
trans(157350727)[request][12.23.28.110]: Signer status: 'Extracted the certificate chain from the BinarySecurityToken having format x509'
trans(157350727)[request][12.23.28.110]: Reject set: Hash values do not match.
trans(157350727)[request][12.23.28.110]: Hash values do not match: 'l6kqP048t5INzJT3W8gxVSXplaE='
```

This hash value in the Digest value in the EncryptedKey reference URI = _1 which refers to Body ID=_1

Used this custom binding

```
 private CustomBinding PeerCustomBinding()
    {

        AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement secBE = AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateDuplexBindingElement();
        secBE.AllowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply = false;
        secBE.RequireSignatureConfirmation = true ;
        secBE.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDesRsa15;
       secBE.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
       X509SecurityTokenParameters x509ProtectionParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters();
       x509ProtectionParameters.RequireDerivedKeys = false;

       x509ProtectionParameters.X509ReferenceStyle = X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.SubjectKeyIdentifier;
       x509ProtectionParameters.ReferenceStyle = SecurityTokenReferenceStyle.Internal;
       x509ProtectionParameters.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient;
       secBE.InitiatorTokenParameters = x509ProtectionParameters;
       secBE.RecipientTokenParameters = x509ProtectionParameters;
       secBE.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;
       secBE.RequireSignatureConfirmation = false;
       secBE.IncludeTimestamp = false;
       CustomTextMessageBindingElement enc = new CustomTextMessageBindingElement(Encoding.UTF8.ToString(), "text/xml", MessageVersion.Soap11);
        HttpsTransportBindingElement b = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        b.RequireClientCertificate = true;
        CustomBinding be = new CustomBinding();
        be.Elements.Add(secBE);
        be.Elements.Add(enc);
        be.Elements.Add(b);
        return be;       
}
```

Edited 06-29
This custom binding does not produce a nonce. So I am adding a Usernametoken with nonce in the CustomTextMessgaeEncoder

```
 public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, this.writerSettings);
            message.WriteMessage(writer);
            writer.Close();

        DateTime created = DateTime.Now;
        string createdStr = created.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ");
            string phrase = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var nonce = GetSHA1String(phrase);
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            b.Append("<Nonce>" + nonce + "</Nonce>");
            stream.Position = 0;
            XElement xmlMessage = XElement.Load(stream);
            XmlDocument dc = new XmlDocument();
            dc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
            dc.LoadXml(xmlMessage.ToString());

                XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr =
                            new XmlNamespaceManager(dc.NameTable);
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("a",
                         @"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("u",
                            @"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("s",
                   @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("o",
                         @"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("e",
             @"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#");
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("sig", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
                string xpathTime = "/s:Envelope/s:Header/o:Security/u:Timestamp";
                string xpathBSToken = "/s:Envelope/s:Header/o:Security/o:BinarySecurityToken[2]";
                string xpathUserToken = "/s:Envelope/s:Header/o:Security/o:BinarySecurityToken[1]";
                XmlNode xmlnodeBS = dc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xpathBSToken, nsmgr);
                XmlNode usernameTokenNode = dc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "o:UsernameToken", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
                XmlElement userElement = usernameTokenNode as XmlElement;
                userElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
                //userElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:wsu:Id", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
                XmlNode userNameNode = dc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "o:Username", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
                userNameNode.InnerXml = "username";
                XmlNode pwdNode = dc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "o:Password", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
                XmlElement pwdElement = pwdNode as XmlElement;
                pwdElement.SetAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
                pwdNode.InnerXml = "password";
                XmlNode NonceNode = dc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "o:Nonce", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
                XmlElement NonceElement = NonceNode as XmlElement;
                NonceNode.InnerXml = nonce;
                XmlNode createNode = dc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "o:Created", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
                XmlElement createdElement = createNode as XmlElement;
                createNode.InnerXml = createdStr;
                usernameTokenNode.AppendChild(userNameNode);
                usernameTokenNode.AppendChild(pwdNode);
                usernameTokenNode.AppendChild(NonceNode);
                usernameTokenNode.AppendChild(createNode);
                XmlNode commonParent = xmlnodeBS.ParentNode;
                commonParent.InsertAfter(usernameTokenNode, xmlnodeBS);
}
```

Thank you
Sun

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
secBE.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.EncryptBeforeSign
```

otherwise the messages really look the same.

Comment: I did that and still no luck :(

Comment: This is what IBM has documented . The hash DataPower generated of the reference node(s) did not match the hash provided by the original signer in the DigestValue node. Typically this is caused by one of the following:  See Edit.. I am doing some XML stuff in the CustomMessageEncoder.. Could be the probable cause

1) The processing policy modified the data 2) The message was modified by a intermediate node 3) Improper handling by the signing application. Not sure which one of these applies to me

Comment: yes the encoder could be the problem. create the token like this instead of encoder: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Nov/24/WCF-WSSecurity-and-WSE-Nonce-Authentication

Comment: In the example Rick uses Usernameovertransport security var security = TransportSecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
 If I had to do this way, I would have to think abt coding for a AsymmetricSecurity.CreateMutualCertificate. If I am creating a customcredentials then the class should also handle binarysecuritytoken instead of just usernametoken? Please suggest?

Comment: try to add the username token to secBE.OperationSupportingTokenParameters

Comment: secBE.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters());

Comment: of course add the token from rick's blog not the regular username params. they will be signed too, don't see an issue with it